# Get all TOKEN transactions by address

Tags: transactions, tokens, addresses, external-api

Given the address of a token, how I can get all the transactions related to that address using JSON RPC or an external api such a api.etherscan.io?

The transactions that gives a Ethereum address are different that the transaction that gives an ERC20 token. Example:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496 https://etherscan.io/token/Aragon?a=0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496

I need to get the two transaction that are registered for Aragon via API.

Comment: Hi there. This is exactly the same (word for word) as your previous question, which was duplicated to another. Can you explain in a bit more detail why you think the previous answers don't apply to token transactions?

Comment: Hi. This is my address https://etherscan.io/token/Aragon?a=0xf9e4f0c2917d29753eca437f94b2997e597f3510 as you can see it has one TxHash: 0xf469b08196e11b...

Now try to find that TxHash in here https://etherscan.io/address/0xf9e4f0c2917d29753eca437f94b2997e597f3510 (same address)

And that list of TX is the same that I am getting via API.

Comment: This list is what I need to get via API: https://etherscan.io/address-tokenpage?a=0xf9e4f0c2917d29753eca437f94b2997e597f3510
Or
https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0x960b236A07cf122663c4303350609A66A7B288C0&a=0xf9e4f0c2917d29753eca437f94b2997e597f3510&mode=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you go to your address page and click `Erc20 Tokens Txns` tab.

[image: Erc20 Token Txns Tab]

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496#tokentxns

Then you look for Aragon in token column and click it.

[image: Aragon in Token column]

You will end up on the page where you can export all your transactions in CSV.

[image: CSV export]

And here is your URL structure:

https://etherscan.io/token/0x960b236a07cf122663c4303350609a66a7b288c0?a=0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496

Just add you address as `?a=0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496` URL parameter to Aragon token URL to get all Aragon transactions for your address.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all `ERC 20` token transactions on address by using **Etherscan API**:

```
http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

for more information you can refer to link given below:

https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

> **Note:** It will returns up to a maximum of the last **10000** transactions only

Comment: Not clear if this question is answered yet. I am still looking for the answer. The API you mention returns the ERC20 transactions only, not the etherium blockchain transactions.

Comment: @user30994, the question is about getting all token transactions. You can refer this link https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts to get other transactions data.

Answer (score 0):

You can search TOKEN transactions via searching for events with specific transfer-from-address, if your token supports it...